# Interacting with DOM from an amp component

Tags: amp-html

When creating an amp component, is it possible to interact with the DOM? For example, when the component loads, find an image and replace it.

Thanks!

Comment: AMP doesn't support **custom** javascript so you cannot handle load event on the client side.